# My app keeps me redirecting to Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I created an MCV 3 app and deployed it to a development server in my organization. It works OK in my development machine. However, I noticed that in the dev server, the application redirects me to Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f web page even after I've logged in correctly. I also see that sometimes some of the assets(CSS, Javascript, images) are not served either.

The error message shown is below. After refreshing the page, the application works just fine. If I don't accesss the app in a little while, the error comes back.
Any ideas?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Account/LogOn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to disable forms authentication in IIS.

Comment: This is not a solution, it's a workaround at the expense of not being able to use Forms Authentication (not a huge loss, but still hackish). For an actual solution please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6304624/120990

Comment: Thanks Dustin. However, the first solution works for me since I'm using AD for authentication. I'm in an enterprise environment where all authentication is controlled by AD.

Comment: It works for you but it isn't a correct "solution" to the original question. As I had to look around a bit for the answer I just thought others might benefit from the link :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly common. For resources style sheets, etc, it's usually a result of not using @Content.Url. My guess is that for the other issues, you might be hardcoding your links instead of using @Url.Action. Again this is common, I have ran into it a bunch of times.

Really basically in development environment you're not really concerned with virtual directories-- however in production environment it's more of an issue.

I would think that /Account/Login points to root directory when using IIS IIS, you want to point to to this route via the virtual directory. If the link is generated through something like <%=Html.ActionLink %>, then you're fine. But if you have some javascript and you're calling a URL, or if your hardcoding your links to /MyController/MyList then it won't find it.

Same with css files. If you look at how the Site.css file is accessed when creating a new project, then you'll see something like this:

**<link href='<%=Url.Content("~/Content.Site.css")%>'** etc.. etc..

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: How about the first time I access the page? When I type the home page URL in the browser. It asks me for my credentials, then redirects me to that error page

Comment: that seems like some sort of IIS configuration.. no?

Comment: That is what I thinking. No idea where to look though

Answer (score 2):

You may be seeing this because your web.config file has the wrong allow role="RoleNameHere"

If you set up your webconfig page for Roles like this below make sure the role matches what you set the login role as. For instance, you may have written `Administrators` instead of the correct `Administrator`. Once you write the role correctly, the ReturnUrl goes away and you can access the page again after logging in.

```
<location path="AdminDepartments.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like ek_ny said, this is very common issue.  You should create these two variables on a global scale for your application.

On the code behind side, put this in a class that can be accessed by all the pages:

```
Public String SiteRootPath = (New Control).ResolveUrl("~/");
```

On the front end, put in the master page file:

```
var jvSiteRootPath="<%=SiteRootPath %>";
```

Now you can use that for all urls that need to be referenced from the root path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable `Anonymous Authentication` of your website along with `Forms Authentication`.

Select your application on `IIS` then in feature view choose authentication .