# MVC website forwards to /Account/Login with only Windows Authentication enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have an MVC3 website set up with only Windows Authentication enabled (so anonymous and forms are disabled). Whenever I try to hit the default page, something forwards me to this URL;

> .../MyApp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fMyApp%2f

And I get an error;

> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /MyApp/Account/Login

There's nothing in my web.config which is configured to look for this URL, but there was a section about using forms authentication which I removed;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Should I have reconfigured this setting instead of removing it outright? I tried adding this in;

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```

But it still forwards back to the same place. Is there anything extra I should be doing here?

Comment: This fixed it for me.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483745/http-error-404-15-not-found-because-the-query-string-is-too-long

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, so I came across the following article: http://martinnormark.com/asp-net-mvc-3-windows-authentication-problem-redirects-to-account-login

And from that, I added the following keys to my web.config in the app settings section:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

And that solved my issue - Windows Authentication now works as expected, and there are no more redirects to a login page that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

When we saw this before; it was related to this auth issue but not solved by any of the solutions

[Forms auth redirecting css/script includes to the login page with HTTP 302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304547/forms-auth-redirecting-css-script-includes-to-the-login-page-with-http-302/6304624#6304624)

Our problem was there was simply an extra folder with dlls copied to the bin dir that should not have been included in the deploy. Manually deleting the bin & obj directories and rebuilding the web app after that cleared it up for us.

Comment: You're a Saint! Cleared down my bin folder and everything is as it should be. There must have been some rouge dlls in there.

Comment: Yippieh. Thanks for that. I had the same problem, deleting bin and obj folder worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have references to `WebMatrix.Data.dll` and `WebMatrix.WebData.dll` files and try removing their references.

And if you've added references via `Add Deployable Dependencies`, also remove from `_bin_deployableAssemblies` folder.