# How to transfer large data from cshtml webpage to IIS express server?

Tags: html, razor, large-data

I am creating a web application using cshtml in Visual Studio Community 2017.
I need to update academic transcript for a class of students in my school.[academic transcript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgglA.jpg)
But when I click "Save" button, the Chrome browser announces the error:
"HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long."
Is there any solution to transfer large data from cshtml webpage to IIS express server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found ...because the query string is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483745/http-error-404-15-not-found-because-the-query-string-is-too-long)

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [POST Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Thank you, Momin. I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Dear Obsidian Age. I did as your instruction but failed.