# How to Specify the "Authorize" at the Area level with Razor Pages?

Tags: authentication, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I am testing the WebApp authentication using simple cookie. The app has 2 areas: Public & Internal (see Area structure at the end of this post). Users are required to login when accessing all pages under the "Internal" area.

**PROGRAM DESCRIPTION**

The App is implemented with .NET 6 with Razor pages (without MVC).  In the **program.cs** file, I tried to specify the "authorize" at the "Area" level for "Internal" area (see code segment here).  The HTML 404.15 error occurred when testing the app (see HTML error in attached image below).

It looks like that "AuthorizeAreaFolder" works fine with any folder name inside of Internal area.  **Is there a way to setup "Authorize" at an Area level?**

**CONFIGURE AUTHORIZE**

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Internal","/");
});
```

**HTML ERROR**
[image]

**WEBAPP AREAS**

[image]

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483745/http-error-404-15-not-found-because-the-query-string-is-too-long

Comment: @mike-brind:  Thanks for the info you provided.  It did fixed the problem with 404.15 error.  After added the [AllAnanymous] in the SignIn.cs program, the config setting of  "options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Internal","/");" is working now.  This allows me to set the "authorize" at the Area level.   Please change your comments to the answer to my posted question, so that I can make it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your signing in page is accessible to anonymous users. An easy way to accomplish this is to add the `AllowAnonymous` attribute to the PageModel class of the relevant page e.g (assuming the signing in page is called Signin):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class SigninModel : PageModel
```