# MVC bundling with jquery not working in debug more

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I'm having the hardest time getting bundling to work in Asp.Net MVC. I have EnableOptimizations set so that I can test the bundles before moving to prod.

Here is my RegisterBundles

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-migrate-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.unobtrusive*"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Here's my _Layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

However, when my page renders, it has these javascript errors. Which tells me that the jquery javascript wasn't loaded. It appears that html was returned. I believe when the bundle tries to retrieve the js, it's actually returning my login page again.

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' jquery:2:0
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' jqueryui:2:0
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' jqueryval:2:0
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you create the project using the default visual studio templates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are protecting parts of your site, then you'll need to exclude the path to the bundle from being protected.

Here is a solution to this problem from another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6304624/84395

Comment: If you're using bundling, then the path to your scripts could be different in debug and release modes.  You might need to allow access at `<location path="bundles">` in your release web.config file, and `<location path="Scripts">` in your debug web.config file.